# Adobe AIR code wont init

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

In my app, the first thing that the init function does is init all the private variables and manage the UI.

For some reason, everything will run fine on my device. I am running v5.1.

However, when my client downloads and runs it on his device none of the code manages any of the UI and it all plays at once.

I figure I might be able to add [this exception tracker](https://github.com/distriqt/ANE-Exceptions) to check, but if none of the code is running I don't know if that will even work.

Has anyone seen this before?

The only time this happened to me was when I had an error in my script but I resolved this. This looks like it's more of a problem with the version of AIR on different Android devices.

His device info:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Update: Theoretically caused by improper permission management when using distriqt's CamerUI and Location service. Try catch catches exception but won't throw it to the exception manager due to the catch and trace.

Comment: Care to share the `init()` function? There is a **stop** command on first frame of the UI movieClip? What happens if you compile an APK with AIR runtime built-in (captive)? That test should eliminate the possible _"AIR versions"_ issue. Otherwise it looks like only you can fix this (how can we re-produce issue?)..

Comment: http://pastebin.com/cYAUUjt3 There's only one frame on the timeline but I have an old stop() function in the main script.

Comment: This issue happens the first and second time. Then, on the third time it prompts the user with this. https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-GiEvmzgxwhg/WKHHD-dca3I/AAAAAAAAANg/LxnUahqtSGEEKcsUBQ8bubkDIg31296wgCL0B/h1600/2017-02-13.jpg

Comment: The app works for my client now but only after those 3 initial attempts.

Comment: Also, my build is including AIR built in.

Comment: Those services are ANEs by https://github.com/distriqt

Comment: Additionally, here is my toggleIntro function http://pastebin.com/Y7dq2V4X

Comment: Last thing to help replicate the issue: here is my application.xml file http://pastebin.com/d9YmELUj

Comment: From Android 6.0 onwards you need to ask for permissions before you use the APIs, this includes using the GPS and camera. Please take a look at this link: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/fp_24_air_24_release_notes.html it explains how to manage permissions.

Comment: Am I not already doing this in my init script? I don't see where my mistake is. I ask for access.... Or am I suppose to do this before I run the init function?

Comment: By moving the init function inside any of the granted access statements I get the same issue. I believe this is the problem as I just replicated it this way. I still don't know the solution..

Comment: If I am using @Mr.Phantom 's Location, CameraUI and Calendar, would I have to request access using Adobe's libraries for camera and location before requesting access through Mr.Phantom's CameraUI and location? In that case, what would I use for Calendar? I seem to be already doing this...

Comment: What is `Dialog.init`and `Dialog.isSupported` doing? Are they AS3 libraries? Do you think the dialog code somehow later triggers your [**issue image**](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-GiEvmzgxwhg/WKHHD-dca3I/AAAAAAAAANg/LxnUahqtSGEEKcsUBQ8bubkDIg31296wgCL0B/h1600/2017-02-13.jpg)? Is that `var alert:DialogView` the issue overlay?

Comment: Dialog also belongs to Distriqt. https://github.com/distriqt/ANE-Dialog No where in my code do I tell dialog to display this prompt. I have no idea whether or not it could trigger it.

Comment: Look at [**your code**](http://pastebin.com/cYAUUjt3) everytime a condition (_eg:_ If/Else) calls a `Dialog.service.create` then its possible that the following `alert.show();` causes an error. See what happens if you comment out `/*...*/` any message related code...

Comment: Those dialog events were recently added to try and fix this problem. The only other instance where a dialog is rendered is by using a service.requestAccess() for the service that is causing an issue after sifting its way through the case statements. So removing them causes the same issue and if I remove requestAccess then I will be unable to ask the user for perms at runtime which is required by Android SDK v23 and up.

Comment: This was confirmed fixed by my client by switching over the target sdk version to 22. Still don't understand the cause...